# Multiple get_dataset concurrently in a dask worker

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

**TL;DR**
If multiple queries come in while another query is downloading the needed datasets - will Dask attempt to download the dataset multiple times? Or will it acknowledge that it's "in flight" and automatically wait for it to complete?

**Background**
If I have a worker who just started up (which has no datasets loaded into memory yet) and my function asks for the dataset it will be downloaded onto the worker as necessary. A simple scenario:

```
(1) Worker boots
(2) Receives query which needs a dataset
(3) Downloads dataset (takes X seconds)
(4) Executes query
```

However, if I have the following scenario:

```
(1) Worker boots
(2) Receives query which needs a dataset
(3) Downloads dataset (takes X seconds)
(4) Receives query which needs the same dataset which is currently downloading - will it download it again or detect in-flight?
(5) Receives another query which needs the same dataset which is currently downloading - will it download it again or detect in-flight?
(6) Execute queries
```

Does Dask attempt to download the dataset multiple times, or will it acknowledge that it's "in flight" and automatically wait for it to complete?

I've read the source code but the dataset publish/list is still a bit of a black box to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each call to `client.get_dataset` is separate, and multiple requests will result in redundant work.  That being said, you shouldn't ever store anything in a dataset other than metadata (like a dask collection that points to remote futures) so this download should only take milliseconds when used correctly.